# Android revoke permissions from Code

Tags: android, android-permissions

My request may seems strange, but I need to reset the permissions from the code.
I ask the permissions like that :

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
}
```

How can I revoke that permission once the user granted it?

Comment: Just wondering, why do you want to revoke it?

Comment: For demo purpose, I need to show several times the flow of permission asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't for the same reason you can't grant them - they must always be under the users control.